# Where do the unstaged changes come from after running `git reset HEAD~3`?

Tags: git

I was on a feature branch, and the working directory is clean, and there is no unstaged or staged changes not committed yet.

Then I hoped to undo several commits. So I ran

```
git reset HEAD~3
```

Then I found there were some unstaged changes, by running `git status`.

- What do the unstaged changes come from?
- Isn't  `git reset HEAD~3` supposed to undo three commits to go back to the fourth latest commit and update the working directory to be the same as the fourth latest commit?

Thanks.

Comment: From the changes you had already done on the revision you were working on?

Answer (score 3):

When you run `git reset HEAD~3` it undo the last 3 commits and keeps the changes of last 3 commits locally (it is by default `mixed reset`).

> --mixed Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are preserved but not marked for commit) and reports what has not been updated. This is the default action.

You can run `git reset --hard HEAD~3` to discard all the changes of last 3 commits.

Comment: Updated answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`git reset HEAD~3` would reset the tip of your current branch to the fourth last commit, in the mean time move the changes from the three commits back into the staging area.

To achieve what you expected, you need `git reset --hard HEAD~3`.

Comment: Thanks. do you mean the unstaged changes reported by `git status` after running `git reset HEAD~3` are the accumulated changes made in the last three commits? (The accumulated changes in teh last three commits may possibly partially cancel out each other)

Comment: Yes, it would be the accumulated changes. If they cancel out each other, you'd only see the end result.

Answer (score 1):

`git reset HEAD~3` is really `git reset --mixed HEAD~3`.

`git reset` has to reset three things to the chosen commit:

- the current branch head
- the staging area (what's going to be the next commit)
- the working copy (what's on disk)

The branch head is always reset. `--soft`, `--mixed`, and `--hard` cryptically control whether the staging area and working copy also get reset.

- `--soft` resets just the branch head.
- `--mixed` resets the staging area as well.
- `--hard` resets both the staging area and the working copy.

`git reset HEAD~3` defaults to `--mixed` so it moves the branch to `HEAD~3` and the contents of the staging area as well, but the working copy is left alone. This results in apparently modified, unstaged files, but they're really just whatever was sitting in the working copy before you reset (ie. `HEAD` plus any edits you made).

You can throw them out with a `git checkout .`.

Usually you want `git reset --hard HEAD~3` to reset everything at once.

---

I suggest some aliases to make it clearer what these are to be used for and to avoid typos.

- `redo = reset --soft HEAD^`

Used when the last commit was botched, and you want to do it over again. Since the working copy and staging area are preserved, the repo will be reset to just before you did the last commit.

Or you can do a `git commit --amend` to alter the previous commit.

- `undo = reset --hard HEAD^`

Completely throw out the last commit.

- `clear = reset --hard HEAD`

Throw out all the uncommitted work. That's the staging area and working copy. Handy for when you get the repo into a weird state.